# Delete hidden rows from LibreOffice Calc

Tags: libreoffice

I want to delete all rows except selected rows from a sheet. Rows are selected after applying the filter. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to invert selections directly. Instead, you could negate the filter, for example by adding `NOT()`. Or, copy the selected rows to a new sheet and delete the original.

Related: https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/reverse-selection-using-calc/24538

Answer (score 0):

in your Calc spreadsheet, select the rows you wish to delete by left clicking with your mouse on  the row number whilst holding the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key to obtain multiple selections.

Right click on one of the selected rows and from the drop down menu select "Delete Rows".

This will delete all the selected rows.

Current version tested v7.3.03